# dynamically add textview to layout

Tags: java, android, sqlite, layout

I've been searching on this around here but I cant seem to find the right source/answer for this.

I want to pull data from my SQLite DB and display it in the layout (with TextViews), according to the number of elements I have in the DB.

How do I add TextViews to the layout "on the fly"?
hardcoding textviews is very simple but I have no idea how to it dynamically.
thanks for any help!

here is my class:

```
package android.GUI;


 public class Shifts extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

String dbTime;

DBAdapter DB = new DBAdapter(this);

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.shifts);

    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.shifts);
    TextView text = new TextView(this);

    DB.open();
    Cursor c = DB.getAllShifts();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

        } while (c.moveToNext());
        layout.addView(text);
        text.setText(showDB(c));

    }

    DB.close();

}

public String showDB(Cursor c) {
    dbTime = c.getString(1) + "\n" + c.getString(2);

    return dbTime;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used

```
DBAdapter DB = new DBAdapter(this);
```

The line before `Activity` is initiated. So this keyword is causing is null pointer exception.Please write this line on the method `onCreate()` before `db.open();`

Adding dynamically:

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("TaskID");
TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
task = new EditText(this);
task.setMaxWidth(100);
task.setMinHeight(100);
tv1.setText("Task");
id = new EditText(this);
id.setMaxHeight(10);
TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
name = new EditText(this);

name.setMaxHeight(1);
tv2.setText("Name");


LinearLayout l = new LinearLayout(this);
l.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
l.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  
setContentView(l);

l.addView(tv);
l.addView(id);
l.addView(tv1);
l.addView(task);
l.addView(tv2);
```

Comment: thank you, I've moved this line to the onCreate method but its still crashing. any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListView and SimpleCursorAdapter, which automatically creates views for your DB records. http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Or if you still want to manage it by yourself you can use following:

```
// In onCreate method.
// E.g. your topmost view is LinearLayour with id 'layout'.
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
TextView text = new TextView(this);
text.setText("Hello, I'm dynamically added text view");
layout.addView(text).
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I've tried doing this but my activity crashes. Can you look at my code and point me to where I'm wrong and why am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a [ListView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html). To populate data from the db into the list, use a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html)